# How to make main layout adjust with banner admob and how to make Interstitial Admob in Between Level or in the end of activity

Tags: android, layout, admob, banner, interstitial

Halo,

1.How to make main layout adjust with banner admob, I mean when banner ads not yet show up, and after show up, main layout will adjust with banner ads.So, main layout will look smaller after banner ads show up.Banner ads is not a part of main layout.

2.How to make interstitial admob show up in the end of activity or when users close app. 
Because, my intersitital ads always show up in the beginning.

3.Can you give me example code interstitial admob show in between level up in game android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For question no. 2, you need to override onDestroy() or onBackPressed() to show ads. code example:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("Your_add_unit_id_here");



    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
    //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    //.addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
    .build();



    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Call displayInterstitial() function
    displayInterstitial();
    }
    });

    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

It will show interstitial ads after you close the activity with back button